# How to check validation while submitting form using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have one doubt.I need to check the form is properly validate or not at the time of submission using angular.js.I have added `ng-message` to validate the field.I am explaining my code below.

```
<form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Email Id :</span>
<input type="email" name="email" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="User email" ng-model="user_email" >
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.email.$error" ng-if="billdata.email.$touched">
<p ng-message="email" style="color:#F00;">This needs to be a valid email</p>
 </div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Mobile No :</span>
<input type="text" name="mobno" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile No" ng-model="mob_no" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" >
</div>
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="billdata.mobno.$error" ng-if="billdata.mobno.$touched">
<p ng-message="minlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too short.The min length of your mob no should be 10.</p>
<p ng-message="maxlength" style="color:#F00;">This field is too long.The max length of your mob no should be 10.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>    
<div style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px;">
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addUserData();"  id="addProfileData" ng-value="buttonName"  />
<!-- <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" ng-click="addCourseData();">Submit</button>-->
</div>
</form>
```

Here i can get the proper validation message.But here my requirement is when user will click on the submit button how it will check now the form field has the proper data.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy you just have use following code if you just want to know if form is valid or not . You can send the form name as parameter then add following code in function.

```
 $scope.adduserData = function(billdata){
       if(billdata.$valid){
       }else{
       } 
 }  


  <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addUserData(billdata);"/>
```